# 12.04.2 - Sound Blaster ZX card detected, but no sound comes out of my headphones

Tags: 12.04, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I have been having issues with my Sound Blaster ZX sound card in Ubuntu 12.04.2 64-bit. Pavucontrol detects sound from YouTube videos and other things (the sound meter jumps around with the sound), but I can't hear anything. I have tried killing PulseAudio, uninstalling PulseAudio, trying other headphones, and Turning the computer off and then on again.

Ubuntu 12.04.2 64-bit
Kernel Linux 3.5.0-31-generic

Answer (score 0):

just a shot in the dark
you can try them one by one and test each time:

see if anything's muted?

alsamixer?

try selecting a different output device in pavucontrol?

check if your sound blaster zx card is connected properly?
(e.g. extra cables to case etc)

try plugging your headphones in another audio port (if any)?

Comment: I tried all of those, and nothing seems to work.